# How to get full profile information using googleapis under node js?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-api, gmail-api

I tried to use the googleapi@27 to get the profile information but it gave me only following fields.

```
{ 
  emailAddress: 'jainshravan321@gmail.com',
  messagesTotal: 2122,
  threadsTotal: 2111,
  historyId: '116715' 
}
```

I tried above with this(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs?authuser=1) example. I need all of the fields like `firstname, lastname, email address, contact number & all of the fields available in user's profile`. So do you know any way by which i will be getting all of the fields of user's profile using googleapi under node js.

Comment: Please define full profile information what are you expecting to see that your not.   Have you tried the google+ or people apis?

Comment: I already mentioned in the question whatever field i needed. I did not try google+ api. Should i try that or is there any way to get name, contact number and profile picture from gmail apis?

Comment: I guess i am interested in understanding what you mean by  **user's profile**  Which profile are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

> Gets the current user's Gmail profile.

A users gmail profile consists of

```
{
  "emailAddress": string,
  "messagesTotal": integer,
  "threadsTotal": integer,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

The information you are looking for its not part of the Gmail api.   The gmail api is a mail system it is not a user profile system.   You should try looking into the People api or the google+ api.

[People api](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) is basically linked to google contacts so if the user has not filled in this information you wont get it back.    Google+ api is linked to the google plus social media site.  If the user has not set the information public for example phone number you will not be able to see it.

There is no really good way of getting this information back.

Update: after a big of googling it looks like the call for people and google+ is the same endpoint now.  But the data comes from Google+ and contacts combined.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo 
I'll give a try to Google+ api. Most probably it'll solve my problem. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Remember its only going to work if a user has a google+ account.

Comment: Since the module name is googleapi(https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) then it should return the full profile which is existing in google because when we do sign on gmail then there is only one page 
 i.e. google page https://www.google.com/gmail/about/# for creating an account on google. The module name is googleapi which is not specific to gmail only

Comment: Googleapis is a catch all term referring to all of googles APIs.   Each google product is split up under Googleapis,    Google drive API, Google calendar API, Google+ API,  YouTube API.   Are all Google APIs and there for fall under googleapis.  However each api has access to their own data and the data is not normally shared between services.   The scope you request in your code denotes which api you are accessing **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly**

Comment: Oh okay. Now i got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Np it can be confusing its best to understand the full picture then it wont be so hard to get it working :)

Comment: Yeah. correct. Google is awesome. They can't do anything wrong.

Comment: I have a lot of outstanding bugs with them right now so that may not be as true as you would think.

Comment: @DalmTo
Sorry for disturbing again. Can you please help me in this too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831503/how-to-provide-authentication-mechanism-to-a-node-js-app-with-gmail-and-facebook
For facebook part specifically